# Flutter RefreshIndicator doesn't work with TabBar and NestedScrollView

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

my app doesn't run as expected, I expect that when I scroll down my app it will show the refresh indicator and refresh the page. But now when I scroll down the screen, nothing happened. This is the structure of my code

```
return RefreshIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onRefresh: refreshPage,
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                      child: NestedScrollView(
                        controller: _scrollController,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
                          return [
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: SomeWidget(),
                            ),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: SomeWidget(),
                            ),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: SomeWidget(),
                            ),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: SomeWidget(),
                            ),
                            SliverToBoxAdapter(
                              child: DefaultTabController(
                                length: 2,
                                child: TabBar(
                                  tabs: [
                                    Tab(text: "tab1"),
                                    Tab(text: "tab2"),
                                  ],
                                  controller: _tabController,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ];
                        },
                        body: TabBarView(
                           controller: _tabController,
                           children: [
                              WidgetContentTab1(),
                              WidgetContentTab2(),
                           ],
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        );
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
```

Which part that is need to be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I see your are using `ClampingScrollPhysics`

> Scroll physics for environments that prevent the scroll offset from reaching beyond the bounds of the content.

`BouncingScrollPhysics`

> Scroll physics for environments that allow the scroll offset to go beyond the bounds of the content, but then bounce the content back to the edge of those bounds.

you can try changing the scroll physics

Answer (score 1):

**Try by adding this line.**

```
notificationPredicate: (notification) => notification.metrics.axisDirection == AxisDirection.down,
```

E.g.

```
RefreshIndicator(
    notificationPredicate: (notification) => notification.metrics.axisDirection == AxisDirection.down,
    onRefresh: () => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)),
    ...
}
```